# Python app configuration best practices

Tags: python, configuration, flask, ini

I know this issue has been discussed before, but I am struggling to find a starightforward explanation of how to approach configuration between local development and production server.

**What I have done so far:** I had one `my_app_config.py` file that had a section with machine / scenario (test vs production) sections I could just comment out. I would develop with my local machine path hardcoded, test database connection string, my test spreadsheet location, etc. When it comes time to deploy the code to the server, I comment out the "test" section and uncomment the "production section". As you may guess, this is wrought with errors.

I recently adopted the Python ConfigParser library to use `.ini` files. Now, I have the following lines in my code

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'settings',
                                                     'my_app_config.ini')))
database_connect_string_admin = config.get('Database', 'admin_str')
```

The problems with this are many...

1. I need to have the import at the top of every file
2. The filename `my_app_config.ini` can't change. So, I rely on comments within the *content* of the `.ini` file to know which one I'm dealing with. They are stored in a folder tree so I know which is which.
3. notice the path to the config file is defined here. So, depending where the python file lives in the tree structure dictates if I get a copy / paste error.

I tried to set environment variables at the beginning of the program, but all the imports for all modules are performed right away at code launch. I was getting "not found" errors left and right.

**What I want:** To understand how to keep all the configurations stored in one place that is not easy to lose track of what I am doing. I want an easy way to keep these configuration files (ideally one file or script) under version control (security is a whole other issue, I digress). I want to be able to seamlessly switch contexts (local-test, local-production, serverA-test, serverA-production, serverB-test, serverB-production) My app uses

1. `my_app_config.ini` read by my parser
2. `uwsgi.ini` read by the uwsgi application server emperor
3. `web_config.py` used by the flask application
4. `nginx.conf` symlinked to the web server's configuration
5. `celery` configuration

not to mention different paths for everything (ideally handled within the magic config handling genie). I imagine once I figure this out I will be embarrassed it took so long to grasp.

Are Environment variables what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

You have to try [`simple-settings](https://pypi.org/project/simple-settings/). It will resolve all you issues. One way set environment variable

in development

```
$ export SIMPLE_SETTINGS=settings.general,settings.development
$ python app.py
```

in production

```
$ export SIMPLE_SETTINGS=settings.general,settings.production
$ python app.py
```

You can keep `` development.py`and`production.py` not in a repository for security reasons.

Example

settings/general.py

```
SIMPLE_CONF = 'simple'
```

app.py

```
from simple_settings import settings

print(settings.SIMPLE_CONF)
```

The documentation indicated many more features and benefits.